# What keychain content should the ios developer migrate?

Tags: ios, xcode, keychain

I am developing an iPhone App, but I will soon replace my old macbook with a newer one. Which content from the *keychain* should I migrate to be able to continue to develop the App on the new computer?

Comment: Why not take the whole keychain?

Comment: @Wain It is rather large, some stuff is probably obsolete and I would guess that some other stuff might cause some conflicts on the new computer

Comment: This was really a question regarding apple's IDE Xcode. The answer to the question is that Xcode has a feature that helps the developer to migrate all his/her certificates to the new computer. Unfortunately, someone removed the Xcode-tag from my question but I was lucky and got my answer before that. I think the question is relevant on SO. SO contains a lot of questions  on Xcode,  and also many questions on apple's certificates and the App distribution process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to mess with Keychain, Xcode's Organizer allows you to export and import all the certificates, private keys and provisioning profiles in one file.

Under Devices tab in Organizer select your team, click Export and enter file name and password. Then just double-click the file on other machine, enter your password and Xcode will import it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Migration Assistant it all Just Works when you start using the new machine. No faffing with manually copying certificates, etc. over.

Comment: The new machine is not completely new. It has been used for sometime, is the migration assistant still applicative ?

Comment: You can still use it, yes. Best if you create a new user account, though.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I have just followed Filip's advice but next time I'll use the migration assistant